# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError related with a class constructor

Tags: java, scala, nosuchmethoderror

I have the following class signature:

```
public BlockstemRequester(RateLimiter throttler, 
                    String url, List<String> payloadsToBeRequested, List<String> objRef) {
.
.
.
}
```

And I'm using that constructor at this following code:

```
threads.add(new BlockstemRequester(RateLimiter.create(1.0),
              String.format("url...", apiKey), 
              chunks.get(index), 
              chunksObjRef.get(index)))
```

where:

- `RateLimiter` is from `import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter`
- `chunks` is defined as  `val chunks:util.List[util.List[String]] = new util.Vector[util.List[String]]`
- `chunksObjRef` is defined as `val chunksObjRef:util.List[util.List[String]] = new util.Vector[util.List[String]]`

But, unfortunately I'm getting an error telling me that class constructor was not found or defined:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: BlockstemRequester.<init>(Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;)
```

Basically, I'm using this class defined in Scala at my java code project, and I did defined the scala class to use List from java to avoid any problem of incompatible types between the languages.

At runtime I'm getting this following types according to my debug process:

- `chunks` is a `Vector[Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList]`
- `chunksObjRef` is a `Vector[Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList]`

I appreciate any kind of help towards this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved the problem. So this was the scenario: I have a project X and using a library Y. So both X and Y have different definition of the class BlockstemRequester, both with different constructor signatures. I had to change that class name of my project and refactor my code. So, at runtime the constructor pointed out it was that one from my project X and not from that one defined in the library Y

I appreciate any advise if there is any way to approach this problem better than just renaming/refactoring my local classes

Comment: No. You simply shouldn't have conflicting classes like this. OSGi and the upcoming Java 9 module system can help, but only if the classes are private to the module.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html):

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class
>   (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition
>   of that method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this
>   error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has
>   incompatibly changed.

From you question it is not clear if you are getting this at compile time or run time but looks like you are having issue at run time. So, use a Java decompiler and check the `.class` of this class whether this method is present or not.

Most probable root cause of this issue is that library used at compile time have such a method but library used at runtime doesn't have it, and hence `NoSuchMethodError`.

Use decompiler and check `.class` file of the class.

Comment: You just wrote an essay on "NoSuchMethodError" with some misdirecting information (such as: "Use decomputer and check .class file for the class" and stuff about library- where original post clearly says the method is regarding one of the classes user implemented.)

Comment: @tanjir That's where my doubt is because he would have got the error in IDE .. I am expecting some issue with library or .class file version mis-match ..

Comment: @pjj I'm getting that at runtime and yes, I got that error on IDE at runtime

Comment: @pjj I used an online decompiler to upload the jar where is that class BlockstemRequester. But just got .java files. In the correspondent java file I found the method with the right signature.

Comment: @pjj I used an online decompiler to upload the .class file of BlockstemRequester and the signature was there

Comment: Ok. But did you used the same JAR as you are using at runtime. Looks like there are different JARs used at runtime and compile time. If this is inside an application/web server then clear all temporary folders and make sure there is no other similar JAR in the server lib .. It could be possible that same older version of JAR is getting referenced at runtime .. In short, different libraries getting referenced at compile and runtime ..

Comment: So, as I was saying it turned out to be library issue .. At runtime and compile time different libraries were getting used ..

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with your 'typed' list.

If you change the signature to

```
public BlockstemRequester(RateLimiter throttler, 
       String url, List payloadsToBeRequested, List objRef)
```

Or

```
public BlockstemRequester(RateLimiter throttler, 
       String url, List<?> payloadsToBeRequested, List<?> objRef)
```

This will work.

Comment: Another option could be to cast payloadsToBeRequested and objRef to List<String>.